# How to know valid script engine names for CScript.exe's //E:engine option?

Tags: vbscript, jscript, wsh

When you execute a file with .VBS, .JS or .WSF extensions via CScript.exe, they execute correctly:

```
CScript vbsProg.vbs
CScript jsProg.js
CScript wshScript.wsf
```

However, we may use //E:engine option to run VBS or JScript files with different extensions:

```
CScript //E:VBS vbsProg.txt
CScript //E:JScript jsProg.txt
```

**Is there any way to do the same thing with a WSF file?**

```
CScript //E:WhatGoesHere wshScript.txt
```

Is there any place where script engine names are documented? Is there any way to know the names of all installed engines?

Thanks!

Antonio

Comment: I have a similar issue.  I'm trying to call a WSF from another WSF, but it keeps failing.  Have you had any luck?

Comment: @meffordm: See the [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629123/how-to-know-valid-script-engine-names-for-cscript-exes-eengine-option/23328598#23328598) below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is no way to know the names of the installed engines for `CScript //E:` command, there is a very simple way to execute a file with any extension as a .wsf one:

```
CScript wshScript.txt?.wsf
```

Further details at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=33963#p33963).

Answer (score 4):

[EDIT] After reading Ekkehard Horner comment I decide to strike out my first sentence about //E switch.

The WSF itself is a batch-job file that may hold scripts in different languages like:

```
<package>
  <job>
    <script language="VBScript">
      WScript.Echo "Echo from VBScript"
    </script>
    <script language="JScript">
      WScript.Echo("Echo from JScript");
    </script>
    <script language="XYZ">
      //where XYZ s`d be a valid name of installed language
    </script>
  </job>
</package>
```

And `//E` is not applicable to WSF files at all. CScript recognize them only by their extension, that mean the only way to run WSF via CScript is:

```
CScript ScriptName.WSF
```

Comment: "you can't use engine switch //E for something else than VBS or JScript" is wrong. Given an installed ActiveState Perl //E:PerlScript works ok (that I can prove). All installed ActiveScript language names are (probably) valid parameters for //E. However, your conclusion wrt to .WSF may well be right.

Comment: "All installed ActiveScript language names are (probably) valid parameters for //E" - this is new to me, what to say, probably you're rigth.

Comment: +1 for improvement, although I'm very unhappy about the conclusion "no WSF value for the //E: switch".

Comment: Is there any way to know the names of "all installed ActiveScript languages"?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - Thanks, as for WSF... is not Script Engine, right? At least has not such keys into Win Registry.

Comment: @Aacini - This is not easy question for me. Searching into Win Registry... but it's a bit of hell. I hope someone to know better way.